# how to get public information from facebook using app_token instead of user_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get cover photo's automatically from facebook from client's facebook page.

I am using the latest facebook SDK and php.

```
<?php 
require_once('Facebook/autoload.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

class Facebook {
  var $session;

  public function __construct() {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('session');
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
    }
    $permissions = $ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook');
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'), $ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook'));
    $session = new FacebookSession($ci->config->item('app_token', 'facebook'));
  }

  public function get_cover() {
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/coach');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    return $graphObject;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
$data['facebook'] = $this->facebook->get_cover();
$this->load->template('default_template', $data);
```

View:

```
<? foreach($facebook as $fb_item) {
  echo $fb_item->getName();
}
?>
```

I am getting the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: session
>
> Filename: libraries/Facebook.php
>
> Line Number: 26 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given, called in
>   /Users/application/libraries/Facebook.php
>   on line 26 and defined
>
> Filename: Facebook/FacebookRequest.php
>
> Line Number: 182 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: access_token
>
> Filename: Facebook/FacebookRequest.php
>
> Line Number: 203

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `$session` variable is local to your methods – you want to use `$this->session` instead.